# C# For loop after few seconds constant speed immediately complete

Tags: c#, for-loop, graphics

I have this codo for draw rectangles into ImageBox one by one.

```
        g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        int size = 40;
        int squares = 0;

        for (int H = 0; H < 1490; H += size)
        {
            for (int W = 0; W < 1490; W += size)
            {
                var rectangle = new Rectangle(W, H, size, size);
                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Green, 3), rectangle);
                this.Refresh();
                squares++;
                label1.Text = squares.ToString();
            }
        }
```

In Visual Studio everything works as it should  do, but when I build it works for first 300 ~ rectangles and then lag and instantly complete.

I figure that Refresh() stop working.

Comment: A control has 4 properties : Top, Left, Height, Width.  You are not seeing rectangles do to the location.  You need to set rectangle.Top and rectangle.Left.  Your W and H are the Left and Top. postions.  You are just not seeing the rectangles because of there positions.

Comment: He actually sets them, just with misleading names..

Comment: a) you code lacks the definnition of `g`. I hope it is not in the Paint event? b) the Refresh is a terrible waste of time bound to create flicker and whatnot... replace by `pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image;` ! And you will see how fast gdi draw Rectangles.. c) I hope your Image and your PictureBox (That is the correct name!!) are large enough (1490x1490)...

Comment: pictureBox1 is default name from VS. I have g define as Graphics g; and is used in multiple methods. Images are always 1490, I will change size to nice fit. Replacing Refresh() and using sleep to slow down it helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Refresh(); is slow and not effective. Rather use something pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox1.Image;. I used StopWatch with while loop to wait few ms for slowing loop and setting fixed interval even if loop takes more time that others.

Thanks @jdweng (good point) and @TaW (lots of good informations).